# Runtime Error 3134 and Creating new tables (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am getting into VBA prgramming for Access and I was having few difficulties

What I am trying to achieve is this: Based on each entry in one table (Master Table) additional tables will be created to and certain values will be entered in all these tables.

The following is the code for table template creation

```
Function GenerateFPCTable(varRecordFunc As Variant, intColumnFunc As Integer, intRowFunc As Integer)

'' Open Current Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim Flag As Boolean

'' Check if the table exists already
Flag = TableExists(varRecordFunc(intColumnFunc, intRowFunc) & "FPRd")
MsgBox (Flag)
''If True, Exit the function without overwriting.
If Flag Then
    Exit Function
Else
''If false, Create template for entering data
    Set tbl = dbs.CreateTableDef(varRecordFunc(intColumnFunc, intRowFunc) & "FPRd")
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("CT", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("Str", dbInteger)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("FRMBldg", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("FRMEqpt", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("TOBldg", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("TOEqpt", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("Prt", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("Srvc", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("Notes", dbText, 255)
    tbl.Fields.Append fld
    dbs.TableDefs.Append tbl
    Call CreateFPCTableEnteries(varRecordFunc, intRowFunc)
    dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
End If
End Function
```

Then I call a separate function to populate the data into this new table.

```
Public Function CreateFPCTableEnteries(varRecordFunc As Variant, intRowFunc As Integer)

intNumColumns = UBound(varRecordFunc, 1) + 1
Dim strCount As Integer
strandCount = 0

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim qrtStr As String

qryStr = "INSERT INTO " & varRecordFunc(0, intRowFunc) & "FPRd" _
         & "(Str) VALUES (" & strandCount & ")"

Debug.Print qryStr
DoCmd.RunSQL (qryStr)
End function
```

I get a `run-time error 3134 Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`. The debug statement shows the following entry

`INSERT INTO Q-0003FPRd(Str) VALUES (0)`

I am trying to understand where the error is coming from? Furthermore, I did not use the standard SQL method to create the table? Could that be a potential problem? I read that hyphens can cause the problems, could that be it?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Is your value a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
The issue was a table name containing a '`-`'

---

Looks like you are INSERT'ing data before you refresh the tabledefs. Try changing it to:

```
...
dbs.TableDefs.Append tbl
dbs.TableDefs.Refresh
Call CreateFPCTableEnteries(varRecordFunc, intRowFunc)
...
```

It sounds very much like you should be using a single additional table with linked keys instead though! Are you sure [your tables are normalized?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.

I'll take a look into the normalizing the table. You are right on the redundant part but optimizing the whole database will be an ongoing task. As more data gets added on to the master record

Comment: Ah, now I see! You have a dash "`-`" in your table name, that's going to mess up your INSERT statement. Do you _have_ to name it with a dash?

Comment: As you suspect, the hyphen is causing the issue. I'll see what I can do about it. Thanks though. I read that you can use backticks, so I will try that.